# Is there any difference between the terms "paired t-test" and "pairwise t-test"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

What is paired t-test, and under which circumstances should I use paired t-test?
Is there any difference between paired t-test and pairwise t-test?

Answer (score 17):

Roughly, [paired t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) is a t-test in which each subject is compared with itself or, in [other words](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pairedt-Test.html), determines whether they differ from each other in a significant way under the assumptions that the paired differences are independent and identically normally distributed.

Pairwise t-test, on the other hand is a function in R which performs all possible pairwise comparisons. See [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-August/056136.html) discussion for more information